# Where does bootstrap.bundle.min.js come from in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, bundle, minify

When I create a brand new ASP.NET Core web application project, the following markup appears near the end of my *_Layout.cshtml* file.

```
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

However, this file does not exist on disk.

Can someone help me understand where this file is coming from and how I view or change it's content?

Comment: Look for it in wwwroot... so: ...your_project_name\wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js  (bootstrap has a .css and .js file.)  Your lib folder should also have jquery.

Comment: @pcalkins: There is no file with the name *bootstrap.bundle.min.js* at that location.

Comment: You should be able to install it using the package manager.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio

Comment: @pcalkins: It works fine in the browser. My question is where is this file coming from. I have no reason to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studios [file nesting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer) behaviour might make you believe so;
it shows `wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap.js` (image 1 below).

Just expand the collapsed arrows to find that `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` file (image 2).

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're right, it's there. Thanks. I couldn't find documentation on how this works exactly. Can I use this to bundle my own files?

Comment: No, these files are just preinstalled via the project template. The file nesting behaviour is just a visual feature.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification) "ASP.NET Core doesn't provide a native bundling and minification solution." That page has some links to possible Third-party tools, but there are plenty out there.

Comment: For those like me that installed a client side library to update to Bootstrap 5.x, note that the default directory installation path does *not* include "dist" whereas the generated Razor pages do - ie bootstrap\dist\css instead of bootstrap\css. That took me a while to spot!